# Getting NaN instead of a number when calculating a value from a text input even after using the parseInt() method

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

I'm first converting the weight (in lbs) to kilograms multiplying it times kgVal to then divide this weight by the value of heightInMts as follows ((kgs / heightInMts) / heightInMts). Instructions
1. divide your weight in kilograms (kg) by your height in metres (m)
2. then divide the answer by your height again to get your BMI.

```
<h1>BMI calculator</h1>
<div class="contact-clean">
    <form method="post" id="formOne">
      <div>
        <p>Feet</p>
        <input type="number" id="feetInput" class="form-control col-2"/>
      </div>
      <div>
          <p>Inches</p>
          <input type="number" id="inchesInput"  class="form-control col-2"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Weight in pounds</p>
          <input type="number" id="weightInput" class="form-control col-2"/>
          </div>
          <button id="calculate" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <a href="#" class="recalculate hidden">Calculate again!</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var lbs = document.getElementById('weightInput');
var feetInput = document.getElementById('feetInput');
var inchesInput = document.getElementById('inchesInput');

var bmi;
var weight;
var kgVal;
var feet = parseInt(feetInput.value);
var inches = parseInt(inchesInput.value);
var resultOutput = document.getElementById('result');
var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
var heightInMts = parseInt(feet / 3.281);

resultOutput.setAttribute('style','display:none');
var form = document.getElementById('formOne');
var recalculateLink = document.querySelector('a.hidden');

calculate.addEventListener('click', compute);

function compute(){


feet = parseInt(feetInput.value);
inches = parseInt(inchesInput.value);
weight = parseInt(lbs.value);
kgVal = 0.453592;
var kgs = weight * kgVal;
var totalInches = feet * 12 + inches;
bmi = (kgs / heightInMts / heightInMts);


// Hide the form
form.setAttribute('style','display: none');
resultOutput.innerHTML = 'Your BMI is ' + bmi;
resultOutput.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');


recalculateLink.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');

}

// Reopen the form and clear all fields
recalculateLink.addEventListener('click', function () { 
form.setAttribute('style','display: block');
recalculateLink.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
feetInput.value = '';
inchesInput.value = '';
lbs.value = '';
resultOutput.innerHTML = '';
});
```

The value I get is NaN. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in 
the calculation. Thanks.

Comment: One problem I can see is that there is no Javascript.

Comment: Can you add the JS code also as the error is not from template

Answer (score 0):

NaN in javascript comes when you try to do a mathematical operation on two operands that are not numbers and can't be converted to a number

E.G.

```
1 - "a" = NaN
1 * "a" = NaN
1 / "a" = NaN
```

Since in these cases, JS can't convert string "a" to a number and gives NaN.

For more info on NaN, check MDN docs at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: What could I do in this case?

Comment: I tried to upload it but it won't let me. Thank you for helping Satpal Tanan.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper

```
let x = function( i) {
    let r = parseInt( i);
    if ( isNaN( r)) {
        return 0;

    }

    return r;

}

x('fart'); // result 0
```